# Python - how to correctly index numpy array with other numpy arrays, similarly to MATLAB

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, indexing

I'm trying to learn python after years of using MATLAB and this is something I'm really stuck with. I have an array, say 10 by 8. I want to find rows that have value 3 in the first column and take columns "2:" in that row. What I do is:

```
newArray = oldArray[np.asarray(np.where(oldArray[:,0] == 3)), 2:]
```

But that creates a 3-dimensional array with first dimension 1, instead of 2-dimensional array. I'm trying to achieve MATLAB equivalent of

```
newArray = oldArray(find(oldArray(:,1)==3),3:end);
```

Anyone have any thoughts on how to do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Slice` the first column and compare against `3` to give us a mask for selecting rows. After selecting rows by indexing into the first axis/rows of a `2D` array of the input array, we need to select the columns (second axis of array). On your MATLAB code, you have `3:end`, which would translate to `2:` on  NumPy. In MATLAB, you need to specify the end index, in NumPy you don't. So, it simplifies to `2:`, as compared to `3:end` on MATLAB.

Thus, the code would be -

```
oldArray[oldArray[:,0]==3,2:]
```

Sample run -

```
In [352]: a
Out[352]:    |===============>|
array([[1, 0, 4, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2],
       [1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4],
       [1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 0, 4, 2],
       [0, 2, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 0, 3, 4],  <==
       [3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0],  <==
       [2, 0, 4, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1],
       [4, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4],
       [2, 0, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1]])

In [353]: a[a[:,0]==3,2:]
Out[353]: 
array([[2, 4, 2, 0, 3, 4],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0]])
```

---

**Reviewing your code -**

Your code was -

```
In [359]: a[np.asarray(np.where(a[:,0] == 3)), 2:]
Out[359]: 
array([[[2, 4, 2, 0, 3, 4],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0]]])
```

That works too, but creates a `3D` array as listed in the question.

Dissecting into it -

```
In [361]: np.where(a[:,0] == 3)
Out[361]: (array([5, 6]),)
```

We see `np.where` is a tuple of arrays, which are the row and column indices. For a slice of `1D`, you won't have both rows and columns, but 
just one array of indices.

In MATLAB, `find` gives you an array of indices, so there's less confusion -

```
>> a
a =
     3     4     3     3
     2     5     5     2
     2     2     2     3
     5     3     4     4
     4     3     4     2
     3     2     4     2
>> find(a(:,1)==3)
ans =
     1
     6
```

So, to get those indices, get the first array out of it -

```
In [362]: np.where(a[:,0] == 3)[0]
Out[362]: array([5, 6])
```

Use it to index into the first axis and then slice the column from `2` onwards -

```
In [363]: a[np.where(a[:,0] == 3)[0]]
Out[363]: 
array([[3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 0, 3, 4],
       [3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0]])

In [364]: a[np.where(a[:,0] == 3)[0],2:]
Out[364]: 
array([[2, 4, 2, 0, 3, 4],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0]])
```

That gives you the expected output.

---

**Word of caution**

One needs to be careful while indexing into axes with masks or integers.

In theory, the column-indexing there should be equivalent of indexing with `[2,3,4,5,6,7]` for `a` of `8 columns`.

Let's try that -

```
In [370]: a[a[:,0]==3,[2,3,4,5,6,7]]
....
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could ...
     not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (6,)
```

We are triggering *`broadcastable`* indexing there. The elements for indexing into the two axes are of different lengths and are not broadcastable.

Let's verify that. The array for indexing into `rows` -

```
In [374]: a[:,0]==3
Out[374]: array([False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Essentially that's an array of two elements, as there are two `True` elems -

```
In [375]: np.where(a[:,0]==3)[0]
Out[375]: array([5, 6])
```

The array for indexing into columns was `[2,3,4,5,6,7]`, which was of length `6` and thus are not broadcastable against the row indices.

To get to our desired target of selecting row IDs : `5,6` and for each of those rows select column IDs `2,3,4,5,6,7`, we could create `open meshes` with [`np._ix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) that are broadcastable, like so -

```
In [376]: np.ix_(a[:,0]==3, [2,3,4,5,6,7])
Out[376]: 
(array([[5],
        [6]]), array([[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]))
```

Finally, index into input array with those for the desired o/p -

```
In [377]: a[np.ix_(a[:,0]==3, [2,3,4,5,6,7])]
Out[377]: 
array([[2, 4, 2, 0, 3, 4],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0]])
```

Comment: Watch out - that's mixed basic and advanced indexing, which can give [weird surprises](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing).

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for pointing it out! Edited with some details on how it could apply here.

Comment: Bah, that makes perfect sense. Thank you very much for your elaborate answer!